# Internal and Bluetooth speaker 'virtual' wiring

Tags: audio, bluetooth, speakers

I'm trying to run internal speakers and bluetooth speakers at the same time. I have a Samsung ATIV 5 with Win 8.1, and a Bose Soundlink Mini. My Samsung has built in Bluetooth capacity, and JBL sound system internally (sounds awesome for PC speakers!!) I have downloaded 'virtual cables' and a 'virtual mixer" from a link I found on a comment on this site, but there was no documentation on how to use any of it. Anyone have ideas on how to hook this up? The mixer, AISO bridge and cables (virtual) are VB Audio, and my Samsung has Realtek and Qualcomm atheros sound built in

Answer (score 0):

i guess the mixer is "Voicemeeter" from VB-Audio! it will allow you send audio to several audio devices or to audio application as well. there is a complete documentation on the website (www.voicemeeter.com) or you can get the PDF doc from this direct link :
http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/Voicemeeter_UserManualR2.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have the voicemeeter, but not the PDF, so thanks again, I did get it to work once, now I can duplicate it again!!